# Choose the parts between lookahead and lookbehind

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to retrieve data from jobs info and output structured json, one jobs detail like

```
In [185]: text = """Company
     ...: 
     ...: Stack Overflow
     ...: 
     ...: Job Title
     ...: 
     ...: Student
     ...: 
     ...: Job Description
     ...: 
     ...: Our client is providing the innovative technologies, ....
     ...: 
     ...: Requirements
     ...: .....
     ...: About the Company
     ...: 
     ...: At ...., we are a specialized ..
     ...: 
     ...: Contact Info
     ...: ...
     ...: """
```

I tried to extract with named group

```
jobs_regex = re.compile(r"""
(?P<company>Company(?<=Company).*(?:=Job Title))
# the parts between "Company and Job Title
(?P<job_title>Job Title(?<=Job Title).*(?:=Job Description))
# the parts between "Job Title and Job Description
....
""",re.VERBOSE)
```

However, when I run it get empty list

```
In [188]: jobs_regex.findall(text)
Out[188]: []
```

How could I solve the problem with lookaround (?:) (?<=)?

Comment: I'm really unsure but try this pattern
`(?P<company>.*(?<=Company)(?:=Job Title))`
not posting as answer coz very unsure. Basically "Capture every char with positive lookbehind of 'Compagny' and positive lookaround of 'Job Title'"

Comment: By the way just noticed but `(?:)` is NOT a lookaround it's a non-capture group, you are looking for `(?=)`

Comment: Your pattern is `re.VERBOSE` but the pattern contains literal spaces. Escape them (`Job Title` => `Job\ Title`) or replace with `\s`. You also need a `re.S` flag to make `.` match across lines. See https://regex101.com/r/osKpBN/1

Comment: Note that `.*` won't match past the first line without the `re.DOTALL` flag

Comment: Well, it is not quite clear now if you plan to match overlapping matches here. Probably, two separate regexps would be more maintainable.

Comment: It works, the `|` seem very tricky @WiktorStribiżew could you please transmit the comment to answer.

Comment: @Painter Posted with some explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main point here is that your [**`re.VERBOSE`**](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE) pattern treats any literal whitespace as formatting whitespace. To match a literal space in such patterns, you need to escape it, e.g. `Job Description` => `Job\ Description`, or replace with `\s`  shorthand character class. As a side note, if you plan to add `#`  there, also escape this char as it starts a comment in verbose regexps.

Another minor issue is that you try to match two substrings *consecutively*, while they do not follow each other in your input. A possible solution here is to divide the two patterns with an alternation operator, `|`.

Here is a fixed pattern:

```
jobs_regex = re.compile(r"""
    (?<=Company).*?(?:=Job\ Title)
      # the parts between "Company and Job Title
    | # or
    (?P<job_title>Job\ Title).*?(?:Job\ Description)
      # the parts between "Job Title and Job Description
""", re.VERBOSE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/osKpBN/1)

I left the named groups and other groupings that do not harm the regex as it seems to be a part of some longer pattern, please make sure these groupings make sense in your final regex.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you really want to use the lookarounds but here is a simple solution not using them :

```
Company(?P<company>.*)Job Title(?P<job_title>.*)Job Description
```

Answer (score 1):

With this

```
(?P<company>Company(?<=Company).*(?:=Job Title))
```

you unnecessarily require "Company" explicitly to be there, in addition to the positive lookbehind and the lookahead is broken.

So this will fix the problem by ONLY asking for the lookbehind to match and fixing the lookahead:

```
(?P<company>(?<=Company).*(?=Job Title))
```